# Why is my javascript applying css grid properties quickly disappearing?

Tags: javascript, css, css-grid

I am trying to make JS function that on call sets the value of a css grid-template to information from a form however when I call it the grid appears and quickly disappears within a second. From the short amount of time it is there I can also see it is only making rows and no columns.

Edit:
I added a code snippet below

```js
let container = document.getElementById("container");

function createGrid() {
  sizeOfGrid = document.getElementById("gridSize").value;
  container.style.gridTemplate = `repeat(${sizeOfGrid}, 1fr) / repeat(${sizeOfGrid}, 1fr)`;
  for (i = 0; i < sizeOfGrid; i++) {
    for (i = 0; i < sizeOfGrid; i++) {
      console.log(`Creating grid element ${i}`);

      let gridElement = document.createElement("div");
      gridElement.classList.add("gridElement");
      container.appendChild(gridElement);
    }
  }

  gridElement = document.querySelectorAll(".gridElement");
  gridElement.addEventListener("hover", function () {
    gridElement.style.backgroundColor = "black";
  });
}
```

```css
html {
    padding: 50px;
}

#container {
    display: grid;
    height: 800px;
    width: 800px;
}

.gridElement {
    background-color: rgba(69, 69, 69, 0.1);
}

.gridElement:hover {
    background-color: rgba(69, 69, 69, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="settings">
      <h2>Settings</h2>
      <form onsubmit="createGrid()">
        <label for="gridSize">Size of grid?</label>
        <input
          maxlength="2"
          type="number"
          name="gridSize"
          id="gridSize"
        />
        <input type="submit" value="Create!">
      </form>
    </div>



    <br>
    <br>
    <br>

    <div id="container"></div>

    <script src="script.js" async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's probably happening is that your JavaScript is creating invalid CSS so everything disappears since the browser doesn't know how to render your content.

Comment: Have you looked in  your browser's devtools inspect facility to see whether there are any errors in the console or the CSS? And could you give us a runnable snippet so we can see the problem for ourselves. For example at the moment I can't tell where the container element is. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Sorry i'm new to JS but how is this invalid? Isn't grid-template the correct way to do it?

Comment: Yes but repeat requires 2 values - the number to repeat and the size of the column/row. Try doing `repeat(${sizeOfGrid}, 1fr)`

Comment: I just added the 1fr but it didn't fix the problem. Also in the console i found this. ```Uncaught TypeError: gridElement.addEventListener is not a function
    createGrid http://127.0.0.1:5500/script.js:17
    onsubmit http://127.0.0.1:5500/?gridSize=12:1```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems like you're missing with your JS code, i've just changed the submit behavior, using addEventListener and changed the the loop for each result to applay the hover effect and the background,

```js
let container = document.getElementById("container");

document.querySelector('input[type="submit"]').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  sizeOfGrid = document.getElementById("gridSize").value;
  container.style.gridTemplate = `repeat(${sizeOfGrid}, 1fr) / repeat(${sizeOfGrid}, 1fr)`;
  for (i = 0; i < sizeOfGrid; i++) {
    for (i = 0; i < sizeOfGrid; i++) {
      console.log(`Creating grid element ${i}`);

      let gridElement = document.createElement("div");
      gridElement.classList.add("gridElement");
      container.appendChild(gridElement);
    }
  }

  gridElement = document.querySelectorAll(".gridElement");
  gridElement.forEach((elm) => {
    elm.addEventListener("hover", function () {
    elm.style.backgroundColor = "black";
  });
  })
})
```

```css
#container {
    display: grid;
    height: 800px;
    width: 800px;
}

.gridElement {
    background-color: rgba(69, 69, 69, 0.1);
}

.gridElement:hover {
    background-color: rgba(69, 69, 69, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="settings">
  <h2>Settings</h2>
  <form>
    <label for="gridSize">Size of grid?</label>
    <input
      maxlength="2"
      type="number"
      name="gridSize"
      id="gridSize"
      oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);"
    />
    <input type="submit" value="Create!">
  </form>
</div>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Oh wow thanks for the help. But any idea why it only makes the elements horizontally despite the grid being sizeOfGrid*sizeOfGrid large?

Comment: Oh wait I fixed that myself I was being dumb. I used "i" as the variable for the nested for loop too. Thanks for the help!